# Stack memory and swapping under Windows

Tags: windows, memory-management, heap-memory, stack-memory

When Windows OS unloads unused application memory to the swap file, does it distinguish stack and heap? Is it true, that at first the heap will be unloaded, so if you want to create a small array and don't want to initiate hard-disk operations at any step, it would be better to create on stack instead of using VirtualAlloc()?

Comment: Consult the Windows Internals books for detailed info on memory management.

Comment: If the data in question really really must not be paged to disk, use VirtualLock.  Otherwise, don't worry about it - Windows can usually tell what data is best paged better than the programmer can. :-)